# Calculating voltage in RLC circuit

Tags: impedance, current-source, passive-networks

Well I think the prof has made a mistake in one of his exercises, though asking here to be sure, The question is to calculate the supply voltage in the system below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhndlz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now my solution goes as following:
$$\mathbf{Z_1} = R_1 // \mathbf{j}\omega L$$
$$\mathbf{Z_2} = R_2 // \left (-\mathbf{j}\frac{1}{\omega C} \right )$$
$$\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{Z_1} + \mathbf{Z_2}$$
$$U = I\cdot \mathbf{Z}$$

However the prof used only \$\mathbf{Z_2}\$
$$\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{Z_2}$$

This is wrong, right?

Comment: No mistake, just a simplification. Calculate (or approximate) the error introduced by the simplification and you'll see whether or not it is acceptable to make the simplification.

Comment: \$\omega L=5\times 1\mu \Omega\$ and this is a hell of a lot smaller than R1 or the reactance of the capacitor hence Z1 can be ignored in the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because \$Z_{1} << Z_{2}\$, so \$Z = Z_{1}+Z_{2} \approx Z_{2}\$.

At such a low frequency (approximately 1 Hz), \$Z_{L}\$ is very small and \$Z_{C}\$ is very large.

$$ |Z_{1}| = R_{1}||wL = 20 || 5^{-6} \approx 5^-6 \Omega$$
$$|Z_{2}| = R_{2}||1/wC = 30 ||(10^{6}/5) \approx 30 \Omega$$

And \$5^{-6} + 30  \approx 30 \$.
So \$Z \approx Z_{2}\$.

Note that at this low frequency, L is shorting out R1, and C is basically doing nothing.  However, their roles will start reversing when the frequency rises to about 2 MHz.